# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to deploy my project and I'm suddenly getting this error.

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6

Comment: npm has deprecated this package. check https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/698

Comment: the question was discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378071/a-review-ban-that-lets-me-confused-about-good-question-and-highly-upvoted-questi

Comment: Just deleting package-lock.json file & then npm install works fine.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

> tldr;
>
> Holy cow! It turns out that the event-stream package had a vulnerability that allowed a hacker to steal bitcoin.

To fix it you need to update your `event-stream` package.

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
3. Run `npm install`.

This should update your packages to a safe version and you should be good to go.

And here is the official response from the NPM blog:

> Details about the event-stream incident This is an analysis of the
>   event-stream incident of which many of you became aware earlier this
>   week. npm acts immediately to address operational concerns and issues
>   that affect the safety of our community, but we typically perform more
>   thorough analysis before discussing incidents—we know you’ve been
>   waiting.
>
> On the morning of November 26th, npm’s security team was notified of a
>   malicious package that had made its way into event-stream, a popular
>   npm package. After triaging the malware, npm Security responded by
>   removing flatmap-stream and event-stream@3.3.6 from the Registry and
>   taking ownership of the event-stream package to prevent further abuse.
>
> The malicious package was version 0.1.1 of flatmap-stream. This
>   package was added as a direct dependency of the event-stream package
>   by a new maintainer on September 9, 2018, in version 3.3.6. The
>   event-stream package is widely used, but the malicious code targeted
>   developers at a company that had a very specific development
>   environment setup: running the payload in any other environment has no
>   effect. This specific targeting means that, ultimately, most
>   developers would not be affected even if they had mistakenly installed
>   the malicious module.
>
> The injected code targets the Copay application. When a developer at
>   Copay runs one of their release build scripts, the resulting code is
>   modified before being bundled into the application. The code was
>   designed to harvest account details and private keys from accounts
>   having a balance of more than 100 Bitcoin or 1000 Bitcoin Cash.
>
> Copay’s initial response was that that no builds containing this
>   malicious code were released to the public, but we now have
>   confirmation from Copay that “the malicious code was deployed on
>   versions 5.0.2 through 5.1.0.”
>
> The attack This attack started out as a social engineering attack. The
>   attacker, posing as a maintainer, took over maintainership of the
>   event-stream module.
>
> The technical details Here are some technical details that we know
>   about, for those of you interested in this.
>
> The injected code:
>
> Read in AES encrypted data from a file disguised as a test fixture
>   Grabbed the npm package description of the module that imported it,
>   using an automatically set environment variable Used the package
>   description as a key to decrypt a chunk of data pulled in from the
>   disguised file The decrypted data was part of a module, which was then
>   compiled in memory and executed.
>
> This module performed the following actions:
>
> Decrypted another chunk of data from the disguised file Concatenated a
>   small, commented prefix from the first decrypted chunk to the end of
>   the second decrypted chunk Performed minor decoding tasks to transform
>   the concatenated block of code from invalid JS to valid JS (we believe
>   this was done to evade detection by dynamic analysis tools) Wrote this
>   processed block of JS out to a file stored in a dependency that would
>   be packaged by the build scripts: The chunk of code that was written
>   out was the actual malicious code, intended to be run on devices owned
>   by the end users of Copay.
>
> This code would do the following:
>
> Detect the current environment: Mobile/Cordova/Electron Check the
>   Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash balances on the victim’s copay account If the
>   current balance was greater than 100 Bitcoin, or 1000 Bitcoin Cash:
>   Harvest the victim’s account data in full Harvest the victim’s copay
>   private keys Send the victim’s account data/private keys off to a
>   collection service running on 111.90.151.134. For users of the Copay
>   app, bitpay recommends, “If you are using any version from 5.0.2 to
>   5.1.0, you should not run or open the Copay app.”
>
> For npm users, you can check if your project contains the vulnerable
>   dependency by running npm audit. If you have installed the impacted
>   version of this event-stream, we recommend that you update to a later
>   version as soon as possible.

Comment: Or just do `npm list event-stream` and update any top level packages

Comment: Deleting package-lock sounds like a bad idea. Please share the link to the NPM blog post.

Comment: Wow. Is there a link to the article you quoted?
EDIT - Found it: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/180565383195/details-about-the-event-stream-incident

Answer (score 9):

Actually we don't need to update all the packages that depends on event-stream@3.3.6.

You can open the `package-lock.json`, remove all the event-stream references and call `npm install` again. It will be faster.

After that, `npm shrinkwrap && mv npm-shrinwrap.json package-lock.json` should update just the event-stream references and not the whole file

Answer (score 4):

Follow below methods :

1. Delete node_modules and package_lock.json files
2. Run npm list event-stream
3. Run npm audit
4. Run npm cache verify
5. Run npm install
6. Run git add .  (add required files)
7. Run git commit (commit your changes)
8. Run git push (Push your code)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the underlying issue was the `package-lock.json` (the lockfile) contained a deprecated package. Deleting the lockfile and re-installing the dependencies resolved the issue.

The fastest way to do this is these 2 steps:

- delete the `package-lock.json` file
- type `npm i` (or `npm install`) to re-install dependencies

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by the following steps:

1. open your latest log for this error in /node_cache/_logs/xxxx-xx-xxx-debug.log
2. find out the root of  `event-stream` leaf, for example:

```
    45 silly saveTree +-- nodemon@1.18.4
    45 silly saveTree | +-- chokidar@2.0.4
    45 silly saveTree | +-- pstree.remy@1.1.0
    45 silly saveTree | | `-- ps-tree@1.2.0
    45 silly saveTree | |   `-- event-stream@3.3.6
    45 silly saveTree | |     +-- duplexer@0.1.1
    45 silly saveTree | |     +-- from@0.1.7
    45 silly saveTree | |     +-- pause-stream@0.0.11
    45 silly saveTree | |     `-- split@0.3.3
```

3. in this case, the root is nodemon, so you can fix by: npm install nodemon@1.18.4
4. npm install successfully now

Answer (score 2):

I've updated npm-run-all from 4.1.3 to 4.1.5 in package.json (remove in the lock file event stream) 
Then npm install.