# Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, web-deployment

I am currently facing a deployment issue, can anyone help me with it?

**Repo:** https://github.com/PradhumnaPancholi/Mail-it

**Error Msg**:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2019-01-13T14:47:41.909830+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-01-13T14:47:41.911756+00:00 app[web.1]:  

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mailit7.herokuapp.com request_id=3e7925be-a220-4cad-a883-a012a954dd46 fwd="174.117.19.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

heroku log: I have a new error msg now.

```
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
  method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
  host=mailit7.herokuapp.com 
  request_id=3ca9c4a6-c7be-4cdd-bff5-57334a081a96 
  fwd="174.117.19.190" 
  dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Comment: Make sure that `npm install` is done correctly. You can try to delete or cut the `node_modules` directory and reinstall dependencies. Then try again.

Comment: If it's possible, please post the full log of the npm command. I cloned your repo and tried to run `npm install` but I got below error: > npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6 I suggest to remove your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` again. If you got the same error which I got, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578201/npm-err-404-not-found-event-stream3-3-6).

Comment: Tried it but still having issues.

Comment: here's my heroku log, I have a new error msg now. at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mailit7.herokuapp.com request_id=3ca9c4a6-c7be-4cdd-bff5-57334a081a96 fwd="174.117.19.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: Could you install and run the project on your local machine?

Comment: Yup, it works perfectly fine on dev environment

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible, please post the full log of the npm command.
I cloned your repo and tried to run `npm install` but I got below error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@3.3.6

I suggest to remove your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` again. If you got the same error which I got, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578201/npm-err-404-not-found-event-stream3-3-6).

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a sever like that, what you need to do is command dir/s and check to see if your computer can handle it. But if you're just looking for a back door to a private server, then hit cmd color a then hir dir. Then nmp. Then hit 'allow connect'. It should restart your computer. Then try again and it should allow it this time.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar problem and npm install -g nodemon worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31663705)

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading the node version resolve this issue..!